# Is it possible to solve $ax + \frac{bx}{y^x} < c $ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

We have the equation:

$$ax + \frac{bx}{y^x} < c $$

Is it possible to rearrange it to have $x$ on its own on the RHS?

Comment: Already for $a=0$ this leads to [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), known to be non-elementary.

Comment: @user28 not likely... but you can get $y = \left(\dfrac{bx}{c-ax}\right)^{1/x}$, for convenient parameters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be solved unless one of a,b,c is zero.

$$ax + \frac{bx}{y^x} < c, \quad  a=0\qquad
\implies \frac{bx}{y^x} < c\qquad \\
\implies
x < \frac{-W_n\big(-\frac{c \log y}{b}\big)}{\log y}\qquad
b,y,(c \log y)\ne0 
\quad n\in\mathbb{ Z}\tag{1}$$

$\\$
$$ax + \frac{bx}{y^x} < c, \qquad b=0\quad
\implies x<\frac{c}{a},\quad a\ne0\tag{2}$$

$\\$
$$ax + \frac{bx}{y^x} < c, \qquad c=0\qquad
\implies a y^x + b < 0\\
\implies x < \frac{\log\frac{-b}{a} + 2 i \pi n}{\log y} 
\qquad   a,b,y,\log y\ne0 
\quad   n \in\mathbb{ Z} \tag{3}
$$

Comment: OP asked to solve for x